# View Most Popular Questions by favorite count / views / votes

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, bookmarks

When can we expect to see a page or pages containing some of the most popular questions on Stack Overflow?

Comment: This is addressed in this related (possibly duplicate) Q&A: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96758/282094 available here:  https://stackexchange.com/digests - where popular questions for each site can be viewed or subscribed to.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Already exists.

Popularity by votes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

Popularity by views (here 250 views as minimum):
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A250

Comment: Any reason for the number being 250?

Comment: Note: This doesn't sort them by views...

Comment: I would like to be able to access a list of all my own questions across the entire SE network where I can sort my views/popularity if this exists...

Comment: Most viewed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git

Comment: This doesn't address favorites.

Answer (score 23):

The **[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)** can be used to find the most viewed questions using [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/291373/most-views) data query.

If you wish you can make a [fork of the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/291373) to customise the results displayed to include more or less details regarding each question. (e.g. Comments, Answers, Favourites, Votes)

Change the last line:

```
ORDER BY ViewCount DESC
```

to

```
ORDER BY AnswerCount DESC
```

to sort by answers, or

```
ORDER BY FavoriteCount DESC
```

to sort by favorites, or

```
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

to sort by votes/score.

Comment: I found this simple one http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/132181/most-favorited-questions

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses favorites.

Comment: Here is another more simple answer based on Aquarius Power's comment with more options and info: https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/a/576/48663