# How can my question be chosen for the newsletter?

Tags: discussion, support, newsletter

Are questions automatically chosen, or must they meet a range of conditions?

Is the number of questions limited? Or will all questions, that meet the conditions, be in the newsletter?

Comment: Lots of ¤cough¤ *cash* couldn't hurt. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [discussion page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96758/148310):

Your question needs to meet one of these requirements:

- Be a [Hot question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected/4789#4789) for the week.
- Be a Random, unanswered question... more than a few hours old and >0 score.
- Entice a site mod to pick it as a hot question.

Comment: Apparently unicorns and waffles help around here, but perhaps narwahls (sp?) would be more appropriate enticements for Stack Overflow.