# Can we be informed about actions on site-meta posts?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, global-inbox, per-site-meta

Can we be informed about activity on our meta posts? For example upvotes might have a grey icon in the rep notification menu? Something like this:
[image]
And for comments it is the same.

Instead of not knowing anything and only coming back a few days later when you get some badge. And we can also be informed about things like question closes.

Also, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200301/allow-me-to-get-notifications-for-new-meta-posts-like-mods-do) is not what I'm looking for. I'm not a mod!

Comment: Comments are already notified just fine. Upvote notifications might be nice, I guess.

Comment: The proposed dupe doesn't cover notification for closures, which isn't currently implemented anywhere (main or meta).  There's almost certainly a feature request for that here somewhere.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: [Yeah](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/274165).