# Get an email containing the most discussed questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, notifications, email-notification, hot-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weekly site newsletters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96758/weekly-site-newsletters)

I want to read the most interesting questions on Stack Overflow, is there a way to recieve email containing the most discused questions on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help you :

https://stackexchange.com/newsletters

I am currently subscribed to the Meta newsletter and it contains -

- Top new questions this week
- Greatest hits from previous weeks
- Can you answer these? (A list of some unanswered questions)

It is also possible to see a preview of what the newsletter will look like :

[image]