# Newsletter: "can you answer these?" section - is it unique for each recipient?

Tags: support, newsletter

In the ServerFault weekly newsletter, there is a section labelled "Can you answer these?". How is the questions in this section selected, and does each recipient of the newsletter get a different set of questions?

Edit 1:
For the newsletter dated Tuesday, May 22, 2012 I received (in this order):

- [Deleting certain files sits at "preparing to recycle" on Windows 7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/389682/deleting-certain-files-sits-at-preparing-to-recycle-on-windows-7?newsletter=1&nlcode=1524%7c7dec)
- [Nagios performance graphs](https://serverfault.com/questions/390598/nagios-performance-graphs?newsletter=1&nlcode=1524%7c7dec)
- [Configuring Cassandra for consistency across multiple datacenters](https://serverfault.com/questions/391234/configuring-cassandra-for-consistency-across-multiple-datacenters?newsletter=1&nlcode=1524%7c7dec)

What did you get?

Edit 2:
The newsletter can be found on your profile edit page (as shown):

[image: newsletter tick-box]

or as described here:
[Weekly site newsletters? on Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96758/weekly-site-newsletters)

Apparently far less people know about them that I realised! I remember seeing the banner add yonks ago.

Comment: There's a newsletter?

Comment: Tell us what was in that section for your last newsletter and the date it was released.

Comment: Updated with last week's newletter's details

Comment: @Ashley, definitely not trolling. I've never seen a mention of a newsletter and searching for the word on the SF front page turns up zero results, so I can only assume they don't want everyone to know about it.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers see image and link :)

Comment: @Ashley, that link is on MSO, so it's no wonder I haven't seen it. MSO is an unpleasant and unfriendly place and I don't like to go there. You'll also note from the upvotes on my original comment that I'm not the only one who was unaware of a newsletter.

Comment: @John MSO is only unfriendly to those who don't read (or think) before they post. Besides, participation isn't required to *read* MSO and learn about new features.  :)

Comment: Why was my question moved to Stack Overflow's Meta? The madness of migration in StackExchange sites does my head in. This post is in no way relevant to StackOverflow.

Comment: Note that Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange *are one and the same* (notice where your link to "Meta Stack Exchange" goes).  :)

Comment: My head aslode. I've had questions migrated poorly before with no explanation or way to query... This time it seems valid... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not quite. Whenever a batch of newsletters is to be sent, we query for the 20 highest voted questions that have no answers, are open, have score >= 0, and were asked between 7 days and 6 hours ago. Then, for each individual newsletter, 3 of the 20 are randomly selected for inclusion.

So, on a small site on which only one question matches these criteria, it's possible that *everyone* gets the same "can you answer this?" question. But on a bigger site, it's also possible that everyone receives a different set.

Long-term plans for the newsletter (and Stack Exchange in general) include greater personalization, so this may change in the future as newsletters become more targeted.

Comment: Bam. Just like that. Thanks. :)