# Monthly Newsletter

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

I would appreciate a **monthly** newsletter which contains the top questions of the respective month. I often find myself reading top questions with a lot of votes and answers.

I know there is a **weekly** newsletter! I think the quality of a monthly newsletter is better, that is why I would appreciate it.

Instead of having to visit https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month for example every month, you would simply receive the top questions via email.

There is a lot of potential in the newsletter system in my opinion, you could create options such as frequency and newsletter content (top questions and/or specific tags). Hence users could configure their newsletter. But that is another discussion which should take place in [Can newsletters take into account a user's favorite tags on that site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110902/can-newsletters-take-into-account-a-users-favorite-tags-on-that-site)

All I am asking for is the option to subscribe to a monthly newsletter, which contains the top questions of the respective month.

*Update*

[Emmett](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/144066/emmett) wrote in [Newsletter: “can you answer these?” section - is it unique for each recipient?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134031/191940):

> Long-term plans for the newsletter (and Stack Exchange in general) include greater personalization, so this may change in the future as newsletters become more targeted.

Can someone confirm that this is an upcoming feature?

Comment: There's a weekly newsletter, do you already subscribe to that?

Comment: Evidently not....

Comment: `Of course I know theres a weekly newsletter!` That was not evident until you told us. :-P

Comment: I subscribed to the weekly newsletter but unsubscribed shortly after, because it was too much and the questions and answers were not very interesting (yet) in my opinion.

Comment: An option to receive it either weekly or monthly (or fortnightly, etc) would be interesting...I wonder how popular it would be?

Comment: You know, if you **SCREAM IN BOLDED ALL CAPS**, it doesn't exactly endear you to your audience...

Comment: Thanks Jim, that was what I have been thinking. You could basically extend the whole newsletter system with a few options the user can select: frequency, content of newsletter (top questions and/or specific tags?),... Sorry for the misunderstanding I hope we can get a discussion started now.

Comment: I have not subscribed to the newsletter specifically because I'm trying to cut down on the volume of automated e-mail that I receive. I can see value in a monthly option and I can't see how it would be difficult to implement, though every time I say that one of the developers shoots me with 'caching' ...

Answer (score 4):

This already exists in weekly form ([here's a description of contents](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121634/164454)) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121631/how-do-i-subscribe-for-a-sites-weekly-email-newsletter) is information on how to subscribe.

It contains:

- The Top New Questions of the week.
- Some selected highlight questions from previous weeks.
- Some selected unanswered questions from the
  past.

Comment: +1 for including links to the description of the contents. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can already get a *weekly* newsletter for any given StackExchange website [on the StackExchange site](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters).