# Let me choose newsletter range (e.g. monthly, weekly, etc)

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

There is currently only a weekly newsletter (Top questions and answers, Important announcements and Unanswered questions etc).

Can I select "monthly", "two-monthly", "five-weekly", etc instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monthly Newsletter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141664/monthly-newsletter)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, the other question sort-of mixes existance of newsletters itself, and their frequency. Even the answer there is completely misleading and doesn't quite apply. It doesn't look like an exact duplicate, nor like a "this question already has an answer here" case.

Comment: @tohecz the answers are not relevant indeed, but the root request is the same: choosing a monthly newsletter instead of a weekly one. "this question already has an answer here" rule does not apply in Meta otherwise we'll be flooded with identical bug reports and feature requests.