# Should we start a monthly magazine "SE Today" with all the top questions explained

Tags: discussion

I am thinking it will be good if we can start a monthly magazine in which all the top voted questions & answers will be published and explained.

It will be useful for people who are travelling or who don't have internet access on free time places.

Comment: Also the revenue generated will be donated for charity or buying new RAM for servers

Comment: I think this idea is ultimately flawed. The amount of revision needed to turn Q&A questions into good magazine content is significant. It would at least be "SE a month ago". And the idea that there is enough revenue to be made to break even, let alone make a profit, might not be all that realistic.

Comment: You mean an actual paper magazine (implausible), or a formatted PDF?

Answer (score 5):

Doing something like this would be moving us backwards as a society. In my workplace, we've just about eliminated the use of paper. Everything we do is paperless. Even HR forms that we fill out are done digitally. I can barely remember how to print anything anymore as it's been so long since I've printed anything.

I'd like to think that Stack Exchange is just as progressive, forward-thinking, and green when it comes to reducing their carbon footprint. The amount of paper that would go into these magazines, for worldwide distribution, would be staggering.

Plus, it would be a waste of time, as darvidsOn says, since the Internet and the digital world have enabled content to constantly improve. Printed media just cannot compete.

As for being away from the Internet, perhaps there's another solution you could think about and propose. For instance, if the [Weekly Site Newsletters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96758/weekly-site-newsletters) could be downloaded, that would be a good possible first start. Anything that would involve downloading content to your smartphone *before* you go on that Arctic vacation could solve this issue. ;)  You don't need Internet to read content offline. ;)

Comment: Yup. 1 printer in 5 offices between 70 people in my location.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point of actually publishing a magazine for all the reasons already stated plus one more.

There is already a forum where this can occur, [the blogs](https://stackexchange.com/blogs). Rebecca Chernoff's [original blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) outlining the "official" site-specific blogs explicitly encourages this:

> Highlight top content. What great question was posted on the site
> recently?  Recognize it!  Don’t just copy the question and its answers
> to the blog, blog about the question and its answers.  A fine line
> there, eh?  Delve deeper into the question or an answer.  Add more
> context.  Compare or analyze answers against each other.  There is a
> lot to work with here.

If you'd like to do an in-depth analysis of a question then submit something! Unless of course you'd like someone else to do all the work? If that's the case then you're going to have to encourage them to do so.

Unfortunately blog.stackexchange.com and block.stackoverflow.com are currently the same thing. There is no dedicated Stack Overflow blog, so you might have to do as Rebecca suggest in order to get a Stack Overflow specific blog started:

> #### So how does my site get a community blog?
>
> Starting a blog is easy.  Keeping up a blog, contributing to it regularly is difficult.  Blogs
> are hard work.  Wanting a blog is obviously the first step, but there
> are a few things that the community needs to discuss in order to get a
> blog going.
>
> **Raise the idea on the child meta.** A community blog needs the involvement of community members.  These blogs don’t exist to be the
> personal blog of a community member.  They are both for and run by the
> community.  It needs to be something the community collectively wants
> and will cultivate.
>
> **Define the scope and purpose of the blog.** Is the blog about the site? Is it about the site’s topic? Is it about the industry around
> the topic? Keep in mind the audience of your community and their
> interests. Another generic blog about  may not be all that
> interesting.  A community blog should be interesting to both current
> members and potential new members.
>
> **Recruit contributors.** Who will write entries for the blog? Starting a blog is a bit like going through the buffet line. Be
> realistic – don’t let your eyes be bigger than your stomach. Think
> seriously about if and how often you will be able to contribute a blog
> post, including research/prep time.  The more contributors there are,
> the less frequently each contributor needs to post.  One post a month
> is a much easier to stomach than a couple posts every week.
>
> **Plan a schedule.** Given the results of steps #2 and #3, think about a rough idea of a schedule for the blog. Will there be one post a
> week, posted Mondays? Will there be  posts on Tuesdays and 
> posts on Fridays? You don’t need to be pushing out posts daily, but
> you should post at least once a week.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good use of SE employees' time.

Even if it was done on a volunteer basis, the combined knowledge required to *explain* top questions across all SE network sites means that at least <del>a dozen</del> **20** different people would have to contribute, and the specific expertise required would change every month. The logistics involved is mind-boggling.