# Best questions ever

Tags: discussion, questions, books

As you may have noticed from the news, Quora created a pdf with the best questions ever asked in their site, and distributed freely to the public. I think it would be a good idea to make a similar book in stackexchange. The tons of knowledge by the experts here are worth spreading in the world.

What do you think about that?
Of course, I am at your disposal for any help needed.
Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Yeah right...are you capable to find the best threads in seconds? And I am not talking just from rating scope. And in which way does it downgrade the value of the questions?

Comment: Tip: link to things you talk about in a question.

Comment: What benefit comes from collecting questions of random topics and putting it in a PDF?

Comment: Yeah, I don't really see the point either. Putting freely available content into a PDF just degrades it - seeing as it can no longer be edited and new content added. Maybe this made sense for Quora because some of their stuff isn't publicly available without an invite (right? Not sure), but Stack Exchange's top content is available to anyone, 24 hours a day

Comment: [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes).

Comment: Sort of dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153158/should-we-start-a-monthly-magazine-se-today-with-all-the-top-questions-explain/153174

Comment: Check my edits please

Comment: Even with your most recent edit, the "best" questions will be different for each person. When all the information is already freely acceptable and searchable, why would you want it in PDF form?

Comment: It is called entropy...too much noise, duplicates, and hidden treasures

Answer (score 13):

This makes much more sense for Quora than Stack Exchange, don't forget that Quora will not let you see answers to their questions if you are not logged in. That, of course, it's not the case with Stack Exchange, which makes a PDF compilation of our top content way less interesting and/or valuable, Stack Exchange's content is already distributed freely by default.

Comment: As I am saying in my edit, I dont see how are they becoming less valuable. You have a strongly point in the publicity of the questions, but it is not enough to devalue the requsest so much.

Comment: Also, Quora's questions and answers tend to be about broader, more discussion-oriented topics. These work for a general audience, where a [question about jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery) will only really be of interest to those working with that technology.

Answer (score 0):

> Yeah right...are you capable to find the best threads in seconds?

Well...I can find the *highest voted questions* in seconds:

[image]

and with the chiselling away at the hoards of bikeshed list many of the questions that show on the first page with that sorting are actually, you know, *good*.

Comment: Even better, [Greatest hits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits)

Comment: Thank you Sathya, I didnt know this, it is a good propose
@dmckee: Please quote my full words, not only thoses that fit your desired answer. For the record: "...And I am not talking just from rating scope..."

Comment: @peraueb what scope are you thinking about then? If you can come up with a collection of questions that are good by some other criterion than mere votes, *that* might indeed be worth talking about.

Comment: I am thinking of something like Cookbooks. Not only those questions that have high rating but also those that have less attention than they deserve. I dont know the percentage of those and if it is worth spending many human hours to collect them, but as I said in my first post, if there is hidden knowledge it deserves to be spread. The average Joe will not dig the whole stackexchange because it is huge and the free time is insufficient. I just dont know if it is worth making this collection. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @peraueb that might be a viable approach. Maybe it's worth starting a new question with that as focus instead of the PDF publication -  but it would be good to have some concrete examples of such hidden gems at hand then.

Comment: Thats good...I will come back as soon as I have something at hand.