# How can I browse stack Exchange as a "Look at this nice trick"-kind of site?

Tags: discussion, search

The title of this question is not really clear, so let me rephrase this:

From time to time I stumble upon some piece of code or program of which I think: *"Wow, this is incredible handy ! Such a pity that I only now find out that this exists..."* . The problem here is that you can only find these things by accident because you didn't even know there was something to search for.

So what I'm wondering about, (How) Can I use Stack Exchange in such a way that it can just find the most interesting answers of the week without actually searching for answers for a specific question ?

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot for example

Comment: Btw your question body/title is a little bit misleading. It first reads like you found some code _somewhere else_ and want to share it here.

Comment: That will give me interesting questions, but that's not the purpose. The questions can be questions that are trivial to solve and/or really boring. It's the answers that matter to me

Comment: True... I couldn't think of a clear question that would be short enough to fit in the title. This is the best I could think off to keep it both short and related to the real question

Comment: Won't these just be the most highly upvoted answers of the previous week?

Comment: Not sure about this... I think the highest up-voted answers will just be the clearest explanations.But they won't necessarily introduce new ideas. (I assume in most cases it will even be the opposite, the answer that will get the highest votes will be a answer that most people already know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use stackexchange in such a way that it can just find the most interesting answers of the week without actually searching for answers for a specific question ?

Subscribe to the [Digests](https://stackexchange.com/digests).

For example:

- The [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/digest/preview) and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/digest/preview) Community Digests have:

  - Top new questions this week
  - Greatest hits from previous weeks
  - Can you answer these questions?

Sometimes there are additional categories, the tag for searching for more information is: [newsletter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newsletter). The main Q&A is: "[Weekly site newsletters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96758/weekly-site-newsletters)".

It's also possible to search by [votes and is:answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aanswer&mixed=0), that returns the highest voted answers. You can further [restrict the search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to: **score range**, views, number of answers, dates, and status (such as open, closed, locked, duplicate, etc.). As an example, adding an operator such as `created:1m` to the above would provide the last month's best answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ask a good detailed question about the issue actually solved by the "trick". If it's an optimization ask about that, etc.
2. Provide a detailed answer explaining how the trick solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Each episode of the new blog called ["The Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.blog/newsletter/) has a hand-picked list of interesting recent questions across the network; mostly technology-oriented but I've seen an English language question as well. Hand-picked, so you can be sure the answers are great as well. It's a nice alternative for the automatically selected options like Hot Network Questions, the Digests (formerly known as newsletters) and the Twitter accounts. It also has links to interesting articles outside the network.

> #### The Overflow
>
> A newsletter by developers, for developers, curated by Cassidy Williams and the Stack Overflow team. Every two weeks we’ll share a collection of great questions from our community, news and articles from our blog, and awesome links from around the web.